# IE8 doesn't prevent uploading with JQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have this code to prevent uploading large files (with JQuery-1.8.3. I'd prefer to keep this version):

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var form = $("#add-attachment");
        if(form.length !== 0)
        {
            var submitted = false;

            form.on('submit', function (e) {
                var file = $("input[type=file]")[0];
                if(submitted == false) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var fileOk;
                    if (typeof file.files === "undefined") fileOk = file;
                    else fileOk = file.files[0];
                    if(fileOk.size > 2000000) {
                        alert("File too large");
                        $("#add-attachment")[0].reset();
                    } else {
                        submitted = true;
                        $(this).submit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script> 

<form id="add-attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div id="form">
        <div>
            <label for="form_file" class="required"></label>
            <input type="file" id="form_file" name="form[file]" required="required">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="4353454554544554545">
     </div>
     <p><small>Tamaño máximo: 2 MB</small></p>
     <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Adjuntar">
</form>
```

This is just executing an `alert` when the file exceeds 2000000B. 
But it's not doing anything on IE8. Any idea of why?

Comment: "Not working" is not a very good problem description, in fact it's hardly a problem description at all. You'll have to narrow it down a bit. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @EmilLundberg - May it's clearer now.

Comment: Any error/exception messages?

Comment: @EmilLundberg - No error/exception messages